# Translate Name and Street address in China

Tags: names

Please help me translate the following:
Contact Name:
何卓宛 
Street Address:
天府大道北路1700号环球中心N2 4栋1单元16层05号 
Street Address 2:

City: cheng du shi 
State/Province/Region: si chuan sheng 
Country/Region: China

Much appreciated for any help!

Comment: Does the name sound as something like zhangguangbo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 何卓宛

This is someone's name:  **He Zhuowan** (or Hé Zhuōwǎn).  Breaking this down: He [何] Zhuowan [卓宛].  Here, He is the surname, so we might also translate this to Zhuowan He.

> Does the name sound as something like zhangguangbo?

No.  Nothing like that.  I'd guess that's written 张光博 (pronounced Zhāng Guāngbó) in Chinese.

> 天府大道北路1700号

This is the address where a building is located: **Tianfu Avenue North Road, number 1700**.  Breaking this down: Tianfu [天府] Avenue [大道] North [北] Road [路], number [号] 1700.

> 环球中心N2

This seems to be a company name: **Worldwide Center N2**.  Breaking this down:  Worldwide [环球] Center [中心] N2

W2 appears on [Baidu Maps](https://j.map.baidu.com/ca/8p6), and [there's even a photo of W2](https://ss0.baidu.com/94o3dSag_xI4khGko9WTAnF6hhy/map/pic/item/a08b87d6277f9e2f4224ec3b1130e924b899f3f4.jpg).  I'd guess N2 is nearby and looks similar.

> 4栋1单元16层05号

This is the building's address: **Building 4, unit 1, floor 16, number 5**.  Breaking this down:  Building [栋] 4, unit 1 [单元], floor 16 [层], number [号] 5

> City: cheng du shi State/Province/Region: si chuan sheng Country/Region: China

This refers to the city [**Chengdu**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Chengdu) [written 成都市 = "cheng du shi"] in [**Sichuan Province**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Sichuan) [written 四川省 "si chuan sheng"] in China.

Comment: Thank you very much! BTW, Im trying to return the goods on AliExpress back to China so I contacted to the seller and got ba message from him: Name: He Zhuo Wan
Address: TianFuDaDaoBeiLu 1700Hao, Huan QiuZhongXin N2 4Dong 1DanYuan 1605Hao  THANK YOU FOR THE HELP!

Answer (score 0):

When you say translate, you mean you want Pinyin?

Go [here](https://www.chineseconverter.com/en/convert/chinese-to-pinyin)

Paste your Chinese in, get Pinyin!

Or you mean you want

City: cheng du shi State/Province/Region: si chuan sheng Country/Region: China

in Chinese characters??

成都市 四川省 中国

but write it the other way around for China: country, province, city, district, street address:

中国四川省成都市

Comment: thanks for the help! I used your link and it has confirmed that  "TianFuDaDaoBeiLu 1700Hao, Huan QiuZhongXin N2 4Dong 1DanYuan 1605Hao"  is translated as Street Address: No. 05, 16th Floor, Unit 1, Building N2, Global Center, 1700 Tianfu Avenue North Road. YOU ROCK GUYS!